# Do I have to count a book as my single DDAL-legal additional source to use a spell from it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, character-creation, dnd-adventurers-league

In Adventurer's League, you can use the Core PHB and one additional source to create your character.  This is clearly stated applying to races and sub-classes (so you can't have a Purple Dragon Knight Goliath, because two separate books), but does it apply to Spells?

Specifically, If I build a High Elf Fighter, and I choose Green Flame Blade as my High Elf cantrip, am I locked into using Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide as my single additional source?

Comment: Don't change my words.  It's rude.  It offends me.  If I misspell a word, fine, fix a typo, fix an incorrect homophone (their, there, they're).  Don't change my speech patterns, don't change my question, don't change my content, don't change my communications.  It's rude.

Comment: Please see https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1346/23970 for why the title edit is indicated. It's not exactly the same situation, but the reasoning's the same. It's also not clear who you're talking to up there ^^, but please remember that by Terms of Service you've irrevocably licensed what you wrote to SE: if the notion of others editing what you write offends you this may be a poor fit.

Comment: A title of the form "In (tag), (question title)" is specifically a form to avoid per our [help documents](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/tagging). This is a change you'll just have to live with.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Yes, with some exceptions.

The [AL FAQ v. 7.1](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Players-Pack?&affiliate_id=925821) says it all:

> #### Which Spells Can I Learn?
>
> Spells are a class option; any new spells learned by
>   advancing in a class or by feats are subject to PHB+1.
>
> Characters that can prepare spells from a
>   spellbook may copy spells even if those spells aren’t
>   normally found in your character’s PHB+1.

Comment: You can get the "season 7" version from http://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Players-Pack — this (as of this comment) includes FAQ v7.1.

Comment: The DM's Guild always seems to be the better place to get up-to-date DDAL documentation than any WotC page. I suspect the DDAL admins can update DM's Guild directly, while they need to wait on some "web guy" to update the WotC page.