# In Adventurers League, does Magic Initiate let you take a spell that is not in your PHB+1?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, dnd-adventurers-league

In Adventurers League, does Magic Initiate let you take a spell that is not in your PHB+1? We know that "Feats and spells gained by advancement are subject to PHB+1", but in this case Magic Initiate is part of the PHB+1 and that in general is possible obtain spell out the PHB+ if out the advancement in level (see wizards)

Comment: How can you get a spell outside of PHB+1 by circumventing advancement?

Comment: Related: [Do I have to count a book as my single DDAL-legal additional source to use a spell from it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/106571/33707)

Comment: @HonoreShadeshield I think the related question I linked answers your question

Comment: I feel like a few words were accidentally omitted here: "that in general is possible obtain spell out the PHB+ if out the advancement in level (see wizards)"... It's not clear what exactly you're saying there.

Comment: There is nothing "general" about the way wizards learn/know spells - they're probably the most significant deviation from how other classes handle it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### *Magic Initiate* is subject to PHB+1.

You've already quoted the relevant bit of rules text. *Magic Initiate* is a feat and feats are gained by advancement. It is therefore subject to PHB+1.