# Does the PH+1 DDAL rule apply to magic items?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, dnd-adventurers-league

I'm making a Dex-based Eldritch Knight for Adventurer's League. I want to give it the cantrip Green-Flame Blade (from SCAG {this part of the question has been answered}), but the build I'm thinking of would require the Ruby of the War Mage magic item (from XGtE).  Does the PH+1 rule apply to magic items?

Comment: Duplicate/related: [What is the “+1 rule” for Adventurers League?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110848/33204)

Comment: Related: [Do I have to count a book as my single DDAL-legal additional source to use a spell from it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/106571/33204)

Comment: It seems that the Spell portion of this question has already been asked and answered (see related above). Could you edit this down to just asking about magic items?

Comment: Related: [Does the PHB+1 character-building limit in Adventurers League include spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122731/33204)

Comment: Are you asking about having your character start with this item at character creation? Or are you talking about obtaining it at a later time from an adventure?

Comment: Are you playing Eberron or Forgotten Realms? Or are you looking for general answers encompassing both?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of Adventurers League Season Eight, literature version 8.2:

**1. Forgotten Realms: No** - I have found no evidence that Adventurers League grants an exception to the PHB+1 rule which would allow the "This is My Life" option. Logically, opting for the SCAG as your +1 would disallow any and all XGTE options.

**2. Eberron: Yes** - Eberron has different rules, and allows you to draw from any number of the five listed sources. See [this post](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110848/332040) and the accepted answer for details.

Regarding the Ruby of the War Mage, please read [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/107983/33204), where it specifies **"no magic items for sale"** (at character creation). However, the **[Adventurer's League FAQ, v8.2](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/FAQv82.pdf)** does allow for the *possibility* of starting with a Common Magic Item:

> **What About This is My Life?**
>   You may (and really should) use these tables to your heart’s content. However, you may only use the Life Events table once, and must roll on its associated tables; you may not choose the result.
>
> > **Common Magic Items.** If a common magical item is awarded by virtue of your roll, you may choose the item. If you choose armor or a weapon, its type is either leather, scale, or chainmail. No other armor type can be chosen for armor obtained this way

Please note that you can very rarely receive any items from adventures in Adventurers League. From the **[Adventurers League Dungeon Master's Guide, v8.2](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/ALDMGv82.pdf)** (emphasis mine):

> ***Player Rewards***
>
> **Gold and Mundane Treasure.**
>  
>   Any entry of a treasure or award with a monetary value **is ignored**. Other mundane equipment can be used (but not sold) by the characters until the end of the session but **is lost at the end of the session**. Some nonmagical items encountered in hardcover adventures may be unlocked for purchased using treasure checkpoints. The ALCC will contain adventure-specific information regarding these items as well as when to award rewards that serve as exceptions to this paragraph. Any spellbooks recovered by the characters may be kept by one character at the table (determined randomly in case of contention).
>
> **Magic Items.**
>   Unless stated otherwise in the ALCC, magic items specifically mentioned in an encounter become available for the characters in some fashion, depending on its type:
>
> > **- Consumable Magic Items.** Potions, scrolls, and magical ammunition are kept and divided among the characters—encouraging equitable distribution. If more than one player wants an item and the disagreement can’t be resolved, determine the item’s owner randomly (such as by rolling a die).
> >     **- Permanent Magic Items.** Permanent magic items **aren’t kept**; they’re instead unlocked for purchase.

Comment: I think this answer is talking about an in-game sale, not a reward using treasure points... This comment is useful but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It is possible to receive a Common magic item as a beginning character if you use the "This is your life" section from Xanathar's

Comment: @MivaScott Is that DDAL Legal?

Comment: @Davo, per the AL FAQv8.2; **What About This is My Life?** You may (and really should) use these tables to your heart’s content. However, you may only use the Life Events table once, and **must roll** on its associated tables; you **may not** choose the result.Common Magic Items. If a common magical item is awarded by virtue of your roll, you may choose the item. If you choose armor or a weapon, its type is either leather, scale, or chainmail. No other armor type can be chosen for armor obtained this way.

Comment: RE: "You can no longer receive any items from adventures." Can this idea be expanded upon for newcomers? Isn't one of the reasons adventurers adventure the phat loot?

Comment: Thank you for expanding on that, and, wow, to this grognard that sounds *so* weird. Get off my lawn, you kids and your Adventurer's League rules! [*Shakes cane.*]

Comment: This answer seems to be lacking what I consider the most important point: It lists how one can obtain magic items, but it does not explain whether the magic items obtained need to come from the same PHB+1 limitation as character creation.